# Plotting the image of a curve under a complex polynomial using Mathematica

Tags: plotting, complex

I would be able to plot the image of a curve (say the circle with radius $1$ centered at $1+i$) under a complex polynomial (say $p(z)=z^2$) using *Mathematica*.  I know how to find the level curves of $p$, but going the other direction I cannot figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
p[z_] = z^2 + z;
c[t_] = Cos[t] + Sin[t] I;
ParametricPlot[{Re[p[c[t]]], Im[p[c[t]]]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: This returned an empty graph for me.

Comment: Did you get any message? What version are you running?

Comment: For OP's particular example, `ParametricPlot[Through[{Re, Im}[(1 + I + Exp[I t])^2], {t, 0, 2 π}]`. For newer versions, apparently the function `ReIm[]` can be used instead.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept the answer!